# getting sql error 1265 and not sure why

Tags: java, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

getting 1265 error when trying to insert from java app but when trying to insert from phpmyadmin it works fine ?
 any idea why?
  or how can i tell which one of the field is giving the error
 
i am runing a java app that input data to a mysql database
    the insert is the query about to run befor the error happans 
    i lookt up this error 1265 its seem to be happaning when trying to input biger value then alloc for filed in the table 
but when am runing this string of the insert from phpmyadmin it accept it

[image]

```
  insert into delivery (`truckid`, `Factory`, `rangedelivery`, `deliverydate`, `deliveryid`, 
        `costdocument`, `amount`, `completion`, `sumamount`, `pricelist`, `delivery`, 
        `standbytime`, `waiting`, `night`, `descriptionextra`, `extension`, `mixing`, `value`) 
        VALUES ('460', 'N041', '0037', '2016-05-24', '6400439688', '5674250',
        '14.00', '0.00', '14.00', '81.57', '1,141.98', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '', '0.00', '114.20', '1256.18')
        SQLException: Data truncated for column 'delivery' at row 1
        SQLState: 01000
        VendorError: 1265
```

Comment: Please include the code that is trying the insertion. Also, double values do not need to be surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: You cannot use '1,141.98' as an input value. Change it to '1141.98'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove the comma '1,141.98'

```
 insert into delivery (`truckid`, `Factory`, `rangedelivery`, `deliverydate`, `deliveryid`, 
    `costdocument`, `amount`, `completion`, `sumamount`, `pricelist`, `delivery`, 
    `standbytime`, `waiting`, `night`, `descriptionextra`, `extension`, `mixing`, `value`) 
    VALUES ('460', 'N041', '0037', '2016-05-24', '6400439688', '5674250',
    '14.00', '0.00', '14.00', '81.57', '1141.98', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '', '0.00', '114.20', '1256.18')
```

Comment: test.replace(",", "") easy fix :P

Comment: @user1246950   explain better  .. i don't undertsand you comment

Comment: just a func to remove the comma from the string